# Oracle SQL Developer - no ocijdbc12 in java.library.path

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've a virtual machine, the latest version of Oracle SQL Developer (kit with JDK 8 included - although I installed it separately anyway), and there's a 11G Oracle Database.

My TNS file on my machine does not have the list of all databases, instead it it is as per below (there are multiple databases):

```
> CONN_DATA =   (DESCRIPTION =
>     (ADDRESS_LIST =
>       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HOSTNAME)(PORT = XXXX))
>     )
>     (CONNECT_DATA =
>       (SERVICE_NAME = Bob)
>     )   )
```

I tried connecting to one of the databases using multiple methods.

- If I choose the TNS conn type using the dbname as the connect identifier, I get **no ocijdbc12 in
  java.library.path.** I went to the advanced settings, and manually pointed to my TNS file just in case.
- If I choose the Basic connection type, ORCL as
  service name (also tried the database as SID), localhost as hostname or the name of my database, it
  fails to resolve the connection.
- Also tried to use TNS conn type and Network identifier using "CONN_DATA"

I don't have a clue on what to do, similar issues seems to resolve on an environmental variable issue on my machine, but I'm unsure on how to confirm that.

Comment: on TNS connection type, choose network alias vs connect identifier

for basic connection type, you tried service 'Bob', right?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I'm afraid so. I've added that info to the original question.

Comment: what OS are you on? For basic connection type, can you ping HOSTNAME from your virtual machine? and have you confirmed your oracle 11 database is running - assuming it's on the same machine :)

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Windows 7 x64. No I can't ping hostname. I don't really know how that works. I also use PL/SQL developer with no problems, Oracle Home and OCI libraries fields in settings are set to be auto detected...!

Comment: And yes, I would know if production wouldn't be running ;) Those are no local databases, I have no idea what that "HOSTNAME" is and/or if it is used for anything at all.

Comment: if you don't know the name or ip address of your server where the database is and if you cant' ping it, there's no way you can connect to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136466/discussion-between-thatjeffsmith-and-tiago).

Answer (score 13):

Even though this question is rather old, I had the same issue.

The reason was completely different.

I did not have the network aliases set correctly.

Go to Preferences - Database - Advanced and set the path to TNSNames Directory.

Comment: Nice solution! For me helped Go to Preferences - Database - Advanced - Use Oracle Client - Configure - Instant Client.
After that set path to oracle client

Comment: I dont have oracle client on Mac. Where can I get it?

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this issue by using the same path as Gunnar Bernstein.
In SQL Developer "Outils > Préférence > Avancé > Répertoire tnsnames" (yes, i'm French. That' a ;) for french DBA's)
My old `tnsnames path` was `"C:\oracle"`
I updated it to the right path `"c:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\NETWORK\ADMIN"`. And, taaataaammmm `"Status : success"`.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is around setting the correct oracle client and tns names directory only

just posting this answer to help others - there might be different directories structure for the same

```
go to  tools --> preference -->database --> advanced
```

in the lower section

check the box of   --> Use oracle client

then click on --> configures

if your oracle client is already installed correctly

you will see client type -->oracle_home 
if you don't --> select instant client

mostly client installation directory will be

```
for oracle 11g

C:\Apps\oracle\Clients\112_64
```

and

```
for oracle 12c 

C:\Apps\oracle\Clients\12102_64
```

the _64 represents 64 bit client.  if your client is 32 bit --> select _32 folder

then in the tns names directory - put this

```
C:\Apps\oracle\network\admin
```

if this is not the tnsnames directory for you --> try to find

```
find this filename on your computer -->  tnsnames.ora
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found that if you are using a tnsnames.ora file that is on a group drive - if windows "thinks" your not connected to the drives then you will also get this error.

Just open windows explorer and "reconnect" to the group drive and this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved :
The SQL Developer was looking for TNS Names file in the location (c:\users<username>). I placed the file at that location and restarted the SQL Developer and it worked.