# Connection with oracle developer fails (error Test failed: no ocijdbc18 in java.library.path)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to conntect to a database using Oracle SQL developer (error Test failed: no ocijdbc18 in java.library.path)

[image: follow below the picture]

how to solve the error please ask step to solve problem

thank you

Comment: refer the solutions given in (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416946/oracle-sql-developer-no-ocijdbc12-in-java-library-path)

Comment: Did you connect  to DB UTOPIA on same Oracle?

Comment: Why not use a Thin connection?

Comment: actually DB UTOPIA, don't use thin connection because i need to create database on sql developer

Comment: You can't use SQL Developer to create a database

Comment: Found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416946/oracle-sql-developer-no-ocijdbc12-in-java-library-path#

Answer (score 2):

Open preferences, go to Database, Advanced page.

Set a valid Oracle Home - you'll need an oracle client on your machine, and then enable 'use OCI'

Or, if there's a listener running for your database, use a Basic connection instead of bequeath.

Comment: i tried to your answer but also same error status  thank  you

Comment: Version of Oracle db?

Comment: oracle version 11g

Comment: that's really old, i'm not sure you're going to be able to make a bequeath connection with sqldev as we use 18/19c jdbc drivers now, but you'll want to make sure your client setup for sqldev has a thick connection going with an 11204 client - if you are indeed building a NEW database, consider using 19c instead

Comment: Just for clarity for anyone else having this issue - I am using Oracle SQL Developer 19.2.1, and for me the Database:Advanced dialog asks for the path to the TNSnames file, which is my case was:
C:\Oracle\Product\11.2.0\Client_32\Network\Admin\ 
After that I was able to select the right TNS entry in the connection dialog, and everything worked ok.